# A question about the flat band

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, electronic-band-theory

I've heard many about the idea of flat band,but I'm still confused.

We've learn the idea of band from solid state physics. It has origin in ignoring the Coulombic interaction and diagonalizing the **momentum operator**. That's based on the fact that interaction is small.

How ever,in flat band,the effect mass is quite large.The momentum became negligible, the interaction became large. In that situation, why can we still use the band theory which based on momentum is dominating ? What about the wave functions, are they reliable?

The wave functions we derived from band theory is non-interacting. But I see in paper, people like to restrict the Hilbert space in these wave functions and write the second quantized Hamiltionian. But it seems these wave functions seems unreliable, I can't understand the significant of the following steps.

Comment: Flat band is a mode of operation of a semiconductor device, for example LEDs in extreme forward bias. The energy bands are flat over a range of *positions*. It’s not referring to energy band flatness over a range in k-space (momentum).

Comment: "I've heard many about the idea of flat band" Could you expand on this with references to articles? Your question needs more clarity.

Comment: @boyfarrell Despite your assertion, "flat bands" often refer to Bloch bands that are flat in momentum space (ideally dispersionless), such that the kinetic energy is quenched and interactions are enhanced.

Comment: @my2cts  yes,as Anyon said ,I'm refer to Bloch bands.The band length is small,hence more likely a strong correlated system. Like Quantum Hall effects,its band is a line and thus very flat.